# Can't start tomcat7 debug mode on macOS

Tags: eclipse, macos, debugging, tomcat

Here is a summary:

**Objective**: Debug a dynamic web application 
**Environment**: MacOS 10.6.8 / Eclipse Helios 20110218-0911 / Tomcat 7
**Error**: Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.

Story line:

Doing some research on this matter, I found out that the possible problem to this is that I need to start tomcat7 in debug mode which usually acts on port 8000. The command I'm using is `./catalina.sh jpda start` which didn't work (it starts tomcat but doesn't start debug mode). So I tried other things like adding this 
variables to the system:

```
declare -x CATALINA_HOME="/Library/Tomcat" 
declare -x JPDA_ADDRESS="8000"
declare -x JPDA_TRANSPORT="dt_socket"
```

and the problem keeps happening.

this is the return of the command: .`/catalina.sh jpda start`

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Library/Tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Library/Tomcat 
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Library/Tomcat/temp 
Using JRE_HOME:        /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home 
Using CLASSPATH:       /Library/Tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Library/Tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

can anyone help ?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't start with debug ports ? Can you check `ps -ef |grep tomcat` and look for `-agentlib`

Comment: Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Library/Tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -**agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n -**Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Library/Tomcat/endorsed -classpath

Comment: Using this command shows agentlib running on port 8000! but I still get the same error message when trying to debug using eclipse!

Comment: Are you sure you specified the correct port in eclipse?

Comment: Yes Sir! localHost 8000! it denies right away! just for the heck of it , I tried 8080 and it shows connecting progress to 92% then it shows the exact same message

Comment: I also tried turning on some debugging options in Mac java preferences... and nothing.

Comment: Have you tried something else than Eclipse? IDEA, Netbeans? Just tried it with IDEA and it worked just fine here. Did you try `telnet localhost 8000` ?

Comment: telnet localhost 8000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying fe80::1...
telnet: connect to address fe80::1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
same error!

Comment: I started the process from scratch on my iMac (so far I was using my macbook) and THE EXACT same problem happens.

Comment: Try downloading the bin package of Tomcat instead, and just run it from your home folder instead of /Library ?

Comment: this instalation is the bin package. Tomcat is installed in my home folder but what you see there /Library/Tomcat is an alias.

Comment: Hmm - could you try connecting to your local ip instead of localhost,I.e telnet x.x.x.x 8000. Try Running netstat -an as well and post the relevant parts of its output )